# How to remove rows from a data frame when the values in one column are not increasing in a consecutive way

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame on R and I want to remove those rows which are not increasing in a consecutive way in the column B. I mean, the value in each row has to be higher than the previous one but lower than the next one.

I do not want to sort the data frame according to the column B because I want to keep the order in column A.

What I have is this, and I have to remove the starred values.

```
A       B   
26.00   11158115 
27.00   16722714* 
27.08   11881252 
90.25   69428973 
90.27   69749777 
93.30   64207240* 
95.90   71428751 
96.00   71670964 
107.65  100385980 
107.75  226164158* 
107.8   103280320
```

I need this:

```
A       B   
26.00   11158115 
27.08   11881252 
90.25   69428973 
90.27   69749777 
95.90   71428751 
96.00   71670964 
107.65  100385980 
107.80  103280320
```

Comment: Unless you make some assumptions about your data, this sounds a little tricky. Maybe fit a curve to B~A and visually remove outliers.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "visually remove outliers" I  have a kind of big data frame, more than two thousand rows and I have to do this for other data frames, that is why I am trying to find an automatic solution. Also, some of the values of the distribution are not outliers, just these do not meet the condition of being higher than the previous value but lower than the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a better solution, but at least it works.

```
df = read.table(text = "A,B 
26.00,11158115
27.00,16722714
27.08,11881252
90.25,69428973
90.27,69749777
93.30,64207240
95.90,71428751
96.00,71670964
107.65,100385980
107.75,226164158
107.8,103280320", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

r = 2
repeat {

    if ((df$B[r] < df$B[r-1] | df$B[r] > df$B[r+1]) & df$B[r-1] < df$B[r+1]) {
        df <- df[-r,]    
    } else {
        r = r + 1
    }

    if (r == nrow(df)) break
}

df
```

Output:

```
        A         B
1   26.00  11158115
3   27.08  11881252
4   90.25  69428973
5   90.27  69749777
7   95.90  71428751
8   96.00  71670964
9  107.65 100385980
11 107.80 103280320
```

Explanation:

We run through each row of the dataframe from the second element (the first one will always be valid for being the first one). Then, we delete each row with the expected criterion: the value must be higher than the previous one and lower than the next one (`(B[r] < B[r-1] or B[r] > B[r+1]))`. But with this criterion we don't get the expected result so we also verify that the subsequent value is higher than the previous one (`B[r-1] < df$B[r+1]`)

Comment: It worked much better, could you explain your code? why r = 2? Sorry if it is a really basic question but I would like to understand the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @IdaliaRojas, add a little explanation. greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, sort of:

```
A <- c(26.00, 27.00, 27.08, 90.25, 90.27, 93.30, 95.90, 96.00, 107.65, 107.75, 107.8)
B <- c(11158115, 16722714, 11881252, 69428973, 69749777, 64207240, 71428751, 71670964, 100385980,
       226164158, 103280320)
d <- data.frame(A, B)
repeat {
   delta <- diff(d$B)
               # delta gives you the difference between successive values of B
               # delta[1] corresponds to the difference between B[2] and B[1]
   if(all(delta > 0)) {
      break
   }
   iWrong <- 1 + which(delta < 0)
               # '1 +' means that if the next value is not larger than the previous value
               # (delta is not positive), we delete the next value
               # you can remove '1+' and delete this value instead
   d <- d[-iWrong,]
}
```

I say "sort of" because it is unclear for me which rows exactly should be removed.  Why to remove row 2 instead of row 3?  Both will give you increasing values in B.  With my solution you will get:

```
1   26.00  11158115
2   27.00  16722714
4   90.25  69428973
5   90.27  69749777
7   95.90  71428751
8   96.00  71670964
9  107.65 100385980
10 107.75 226164158
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this but I still have values which do not meet the condition of being higher than the previous row, but lower than the next one. The reason to remove the second value, but not the third row is that the data frame I am trying to edit is a genetic map and I want to evaluate each row according to their position, which is given by column A.

Comment: hmm... can you give an example where my code does not work?  Note that in this example B is non-decreasing.  You can make it strictly increasing by changing `>=` to `>`.

Comment: When I tried strictly increasing I have some values which just met one of the two conditions and this are kept in the table,  for example, the starred values:
26/11158115 |
27/16722714 *|
27.5/12170863  |
27.73/12354762|
90.25/69428973|
90.27/69749777|
94/64841576 *
95/65078005 *
95.9/71428751|
96/71670964 |
97.7 /74918081|

Also, could you explain what is the function of  " 1 + which", it is not clear to me.

Comment: You mean you want to remove _first lines that do not match the criterion_?  Note that in my solution the final version also gives an increasing sequence.  Added cpmments to the code